# Maintaining the order of declaration in NamedDomainObjectContainer

Tags: gradle

Is there any way for me to maintain the order of declaration when iterating the items in NamedDomainObjectContainer?

As I understand right now NmaedDomainObjectContainer is using SortedSet as its implementation.  I'm wondering if there is any LinkedHashSet version of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to maintain order of declaration.